# PayPal Error "This Transaction cannot be processed" error code 10004

Tags: paypal

We have credit card Paypal Gateway intregrated  for our shopping cart.But for Makeing Payments from Users sometimes I get this error message as "This Transaction can not be processed ".When i searched for this error code with Standard Paypal error code Its An Error Code of 10004 saying invalid data provided but the problem is that with the same creditials i am able to make payment successfully.This is really causing us to miss the payments from our clients :(

Any help will be really appriciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any correlation id that you received in the PayPal response when you got that error message ?

Comment: HI Eshan.Thanks for your reply.While testing for the same issue i have one correlationid as  "19032a0fd3857"  with me.Will this help to find ot the cause or solution for this issue.Please reply.Thanks